# Entity Framework Fluent API - Map Property to Specific Table

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-fluent-api

I would like to create internal mapping of navigation property to specific table using EF's fluent API.

Meaning - Same type is mapped to different tables according to parent type

(see code below)
Thank you!

```
public record Entity1
{
   public long Id { get; set;}
   public IEnumerable<Identifier> Ids { get; set; } //Map to map to table 'Entity1_Ids'
}

public record Entity2
{
   public long Id { get; set;}
   public Identifier Ids { get; set; } //Map to map to table 'Entity2_Ids'
}

public record Identifier
{
   public long Id { get; set;}
   public string? Type { get; set; }
   public string? Value { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with [Owned Entity Types.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/owned-entities)

eg

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Entity1>().OwnsMany(e => e.Ids).ToTable("Entity1_Ids");
    modelBuilder.Entity<Entity2>().OwnsOne(e => e.Ids).ToTable("Entity2_Ids");

}
```